# Using multiple versions of Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Ubuntu machine where I already have one JDK version which is installed.
Next I have downloaded the second version into `/usr/local`.

Now, I want to run a program against the second JDK which is in `/usr/local`, i.e., I will copy a sample `.java` program in `/usr/local/bin` and then execute it.

But the problem is, even If I navigate to the `/usr/local/bin` and type `$ java -version`, I am getting the one which is installed in the first place. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 6):

type `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

The select the version you want.

And I think this question should be moved to [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Comment: No, the second java is not installed , that is the problem here . I just have a zip file which contains bin and other things , which I have extracted to /usr/local/java

Comment: the the answer below should help

Comment: "Below" meaning "elsewhere" such as sometimes "above" depending on votes, edit history, and the user's preferences.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `java` with no path, then your shell looks in your `$PATH` environment variable to find `java`.
If you want a specific `java`, you need to either change your `$PATH`, or run it with a path, like:

`/usr/local/bin/java`

or if you really want to `cd` there first, you could run

`./java`

from `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: But how to compile, for eg: after cd to /usr/local/java/bin ,executing  $javac sample.java will compile the extracted java or installed java version? because when I cd /usr/local/java/bin and if I type $java -version I still get the version of the one installed before

Comment: `cd` does not change where the shell looks for programs (except when `.` is in the `$PATH`).  You need to use a full or relative path as in my answer, or change your `PATH` environment variable to contain the directory *first* where you want `java` or `javac` (or any other executable) to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach tested on Ubuntu 20.04 which shows adjusting the `javac` and `java` defaults:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
$ java -version
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
$ javac -version
javac 14.0.2
$ update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.14.0-openjdk-amd64      1411       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.14.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1411      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1411      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1411      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1411      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in manual mode
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_275
```

See [Switch between multiple java versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions) on askubuntu for a canonical thread.